# Access to Twitter user's email? (connect.me and fullcontact.com appear to have this functionality)

Tags: twitter

So as far as I knew the twitter doesn't share a users e-mail in the twitter api. 
Reference http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=353

However I've run into multiple products recently that seem to be able to retrieve a user e-mail. connect.me is an example of one that upon sign up with twitter they suddenly have my e-mail.

fullcontact.com I can put in a work related email address and suddenly they know my personal twitter account.

Anyone have any idea how they are doing this. It seems to break the twitter privacy policy, but if it is allowed I know tons of devs that would love to have access to the feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After chatting with some of the twitter devs I've found the connect.me incident was simply my own browser making me look stupid with an auto-fill.

Full-Contact does appear to be doing simple record matching and mining from it's users to expand it's data.

Answer (score 5):

We pull our data from multiple sources across the web, check out the "Where do you get your data?" section of our FAQ for more information http://www.fullcontact.com/api-faq/.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly certain that fullcontact.com is not getting that information from twitter, but using the information they have in their system from other people's contact uploads.  I could be wrong, but they have more information about me than I've given them, certainly, so I'd guess they're doing some database matching.